# Specifying the country column in D3.js pie chart to only list down certain columns

Tags: html, csv, d3.js, visualization, pie-chart

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(['#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16),'#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.deaths; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

d3.csv("Cancer_No_Of_Deaths_per_100000.csv", function(error, data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.deaths = +d.deaths;
  });

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.country + " " + d.data.gender); })
      .on("mouseover", function() {
                pie.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);  
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
                pie.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
      });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", "20px")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.country + " " + d.data.gender; });

});

</script>
```

I want to be able to specify the country column in the csv to only list down only one country in the pie chart example where country = "Afghanistan" whereas the rest of the country will be left out but not deleted in the csv file that I have. The code that I have now is displaying all the countries that are listed in the csv file but I would like to only have one country being retrieved from the csv file.

```
country year    gender  deaths
Afghanistan 2008    Female  97
Afghanistan 2008    Male    108
Albania 2008    Female  126
Albania 2008    Male    172
```

This is a small part of my csv file and the columns are as followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on your data array in your `d3.csv` callback. In the filter callback, you can simply test that the country name is the one that you want. For instance, to get an array of only the rows for Afghanistan, you could do the following:

```
d3.csv('Cancer_No_Of_Deaths_per_100000.csv', function(error, data) {

  var filteredData = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.country === 'Afghanistan';
  });

  // ... create your viz, etc. ...

});
```

Then you would have access to your original dataset as variable `data` and the set with only Afghanistan's data as `filteredData` or whatever you choose to call it.

---

**---EDIT---**

Now your variable `data` will look like:

```
[
  { country: 'Afghanistan', year: '2008', gender: 'Female', deaths: '97' },
  { country: 'Afghanistan', year: '2008', gender: 'Male', deaths: '108' },
  { country: 'Albania', year: '2008', gender: 'Female', deaths: '126' },
  { country: 'Albania', year: '2008', gender: 'Male', deaths: '172' },
  // etc... many other countries...
]
```

And your variable `filteredData` will look like:

```
[
  { country: 'Afghanistan', year: '2008', gender: 'Female', deaths: '97' },
  { country: 'Afghanistan', year: '2008', gender: 'Male', deaths: '108' }
]
```

So you just need to make sure that you use the filtered data in your `pie()` call:

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(filteredData))
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");
```

Comment: But I changed the method to what you have shown above there's still no changes in my page. So what exactly do I have to insert into my codes to allow the filteredData to only show the country which have the value of 'Afghanistan'.